# Market share growth versus last month, last year

Tags: date, powerbi

I have a dataset with monthly sales data by brand. I have a measure which calculates market share %.

I want to add an additional measure which calculates the growth in market share % between the most recent month and the second most recent month. Is this possible

Comment: "I have a dataset with monthly sales data by brand."
Post some data. And your measures. =)